# Run pyspark program in pycharm - windows 11 pro

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, pycharm

I am running pyspark application in my local windows machine (win 11 pro). Installed java , scala , python and pycharm. while running sample code , i am getting below exception. can you please help me on this. I tried all the way to resolve the issue. But i failed in all the options.
Here is my configuration:

```
C:\Users\LENOVO>pyspark
Python 3.10.5 (tags/v3.10.5:f377153, Jun  6 2022, 16:14:13) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
22/12/20 11:23:31 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 3.3.0
      /_/

Using Python version 3.10.5 (tags/v3.10.5:f377153, Jun  6 2022 16:14:13)
Spark context Web UI available at http://host.docker.internal:4040
Spark context available as 'sc' (master = local[*], app id = local-1671515612280).
SparkSession available as 'spark'.

>>> df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema=columns)
>>> df.show()
Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.
22/12/20 11:24:34 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker failed to connect back.
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:189)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:109)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:124)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:164)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:65)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)

22/12/20 11:24:34 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop2\python\pyspark\sql\dataframe.py", line 606, in show
    print(self._jdf.showString(n, 20, vertical))
  File "C:\spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop2\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1321, in __call__
  File "C:\spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop2\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 190, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "C:\spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop2\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o52.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) (host.docker.internal executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker failed to connect back.
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:189)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:109)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:124)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:164)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:65)
        at
```

Comment: maybe first check all the installed tools have been defined in the environment path. Then testing a python script, e.g. test.py, within the import script as follows: `import findspark
findspark.init()    
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession    
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("localtest").config("spark.master", "local").getOrCreate()   
rdd=spark.sparkContext.parallelize([1,2,3,4])   
print (rdd.count())`  If a session can be created and number `4` is printed, it means everything configured correctly. Otherwise, most likely some path not configured correctly.

Comment: Yes.. i tried sample program too.getting the same exception..>>> spark
<pyspark.sql.session.SparkSession object at 0x00000233E4BD6AD0>
>>> sc
<SparkContext master=local[*] appName=PySparkShell>
>>>

Comment: So, basically you can not run the following scripts `import findspark`, `findspark.init()`, `from pyspark.sql import SparkSession`  and `spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("localtest").config("spark.master", "local").getOrCreate()`.  Then this means the setup is not correct. Check whether the versions you have installed are compatible. Maybe using only jave8/java11 and specific pyspark/python version... If you have installed hadoop on windows, you also need to replace a file called winutils (and set environment path as well). The reason is hard to debug, but start by checking one by one.

Comment: The same setup is working for spark and Scala..